# The current path, imgupload/imageprocess, didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a Django app but I'm stuck at this error.
Using the URLconf defined in my_first_site.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
imgupload [name='home']
imgupload imageprocess [name='imageprocess']
admin/
```

here are my files:

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/imgupload/imageprocess" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="image" type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py (This one is from project i.e. my_first_site)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('imgupload',include('imgupload.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
]
```

**urls.py -- (this one is from webapp  i.e. **imgupload**)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    path('imageprocess', views.imageprocess, name='imageprocess'),
    
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def imageprocess(request):
    return render(request,'result.html')
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Result page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is result page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is the error Django giving me]

Comment: Can you shouw the form where you upload the image, so the (relevant parts) of the `home.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a slash at the end of the `imageupload` pattern:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    #              ↓ added a slash
    path('imgupload/',include('imgupload.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),   
]
```

It will thus concatenate the `path` with the `imageupload`, and the `path` with the `imageprocess`, it will *not* join the two strings with a slash, you thus can omit the slash, but then you should visit the path with `imguploadimageprocess`, which is likely *not* what you want.

Comment: thank you I'm new to django, so I didn't knew that but now I think this question does not even worth it to post.

Comment: @AdityaSalve: well some people might misunderstand how paths are "concatenated". It is reasonable that people might think that it joins the two paths with a slash, but it does *not*.